# Real Analysis-convergence of a set using sandwich lemma

Tags: real-analysis, proof-verification, proof-explanation

> I am given the problem that needed me to prove  $\frac{2^k}{k!}$ converges to $0$.

Here is something I had in mind. I would use the sandwich lemma, which resulted in that since $\frac{1}{k!}$converges to 0, and $\frac{2^k}{3^k}$ also converges to 0, and since $$\frac{1}{k!}\leq\frac{2^k}{k!}\leq \frac{2^k}{3^k},$$  $\frac{2^k}{k!}$ converges to $0$. I am not sure if $\frac{2^k}{3^k}$ is greater than or equal to $\frac{2^k}{k!}$ however, and if it is not, I am not sure how to find a equation that is larger than $\frac{2^k}{k!}$

Comment: we are required to use the sandwich lemma

Answer (score 1):

Your argument is not correct.

Use the fact that $k! >(3)(3)...(3)$ ($k-2$ factors) Which gives $0<\frac {2^{k}} {k!} <9(\frac 2 3)^{k}$. Apply Sandwich Theorem and note that $(\frac 2 3)^{k} \to 0$ because $\frac 2 3 <1$.

Answer (score 0):

You are on the right track. Following your approach, in order to apply the sandwich lemma and conclude that the required limit is zero, you should show that **eventually** (i.e. for all positive integer $k$ greater than some constant), the following inequality holds
$$0\leq \frac{2^k}{k!}\leq \left(\frac{2}{3}\right)^k.$$
The inequality on the left is trivial. As a lower bound it suffices to take the constant sequence $0$ instead of $1/k!$ (which is correct too).

For the inequality on the right, we prove by induction that $3^k\leq k!$ for $k\geq 7$. It is true for $k=7$, and, as regards the inductive step, for $k\geq 7$,
$$3^{k+1}=3\cdot 3^k\leq 3\cdot k!\leq (k+1)\cdot k!=(k+1)!.$$

Comment: @LiOu Any comment from your side?

Answer (score 0):

A different approach to your problem. If $b_k$ is the sequence, take $$\lim\limits_{k\to\infty}\displaystyle\frac{\frac{2^{k+1}}{(k+1)!}}{\frac{2^{k}}{k!}}=\lim\limits_{k\to\infty} \frac{2^{k+1}k!}{2^{k}(k+1)!}=\lim\limits_{k\to\infty} \frac{2}{k+1}=0$$Thus, if we take $\varepsilon=1$ there exist $N\in\mathbb{N}$ such that if $n>N$ then $\frac{b_{k+1}}{b_k}<1$, i.e., $b_{k+1}<b_k$. Therefore, the sequence is eventually strictly decreasing and clearly bounded below by $0$. Thus, the sequence $b_k$ is convergent. We claim that $b_k$ converges to $0$. Suppose not, i.e., $b_k$ converges to a number $c$ with $c\neq 0$. Then the subsequence $b_{k+1}$ also converges to $c$ and then we have $$0=\lim\limits_{k\to\infty}\frac{b_{k+1}}{b_k}=\displaystyle\frac{\lim\limits_{k\to\infty} b_{k+1}}{\lim\limits_{k\to\infty} b_k}=\frac{c}{c}=1$$This is impossible. Therefore, $$\lim\limits_{k\to\infty} b_k=\lim\limits_{k\to\infty}\frac{2^k}{k!}=0$$